# SQL combine 2 table and pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I don't understand how PIVOT works in SQL. I have 2 tables and I would like to pivot 1 of them in order to get only 1 table with all the data together. I've attached an image with the tables I have and the result that I would like to get.

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1
    ([serie_id] varchar(4), [Maturity] int, [Strategy] int, [Lifetime] varchar(4), [L_max] decimal(10, 5), [W_max] decimal(10, 5), [H_max] decimal(10, 5))
;

INSERT INTO TABLE1
    ([serie_id], [Maturity], [Strategy], [Lifetime], [L_max], [W_max], [H_max])
VALUES
    ('id_1', 3, 1, '2', 2.200, 1.400, 1.400),
    ('id_2', 3, 1, '2', 3.400, 1.800, 2.100),
    ('id_3', 3, 1, NULL, 24.500, 14.500, 15.000),
    ('id_4', 3, 1, NULL, 28.000, 24.500, 14.000)
;

CREATE TABLE TABLE2
    ([serie_id] varchar(4), [L_value] decimal(10, 5), [lrms] decimal(10, 5), [latTmax] decimal(10, 5), [Rdc] decimal(10, 5))
;

INSERT INTO TABLE2
    ([serie_id], [L_value], [lrms], [latTmax], [Rdc])
VALUES
    ('id_1', 67.000, 400.000, 400.000, 0.250),
    ('id_1', 90.000, 330.000, 330.000, 0.350),
    ('id_1', 120.000, 370.000, 370.000, 0.300),
    ('id_1', 180.000, 330.000, 300.000, 0.350),
    ('id_2', 260.000, 300.000, 300.000, 0.400),
    ('id_2', 360.000, 280.000, 280.000, 0.450),
    ('id_3', 90.000, 370.000, 370.000, 0.300),
    ('id_4', 160.000, 340.000, 340.000, 0.400)
;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cf6bf)

If someone could help me with the SQL query I would appreciate it so much.

Comment: instead of images post sample data with sqlfiddle

Comment: the problem is that I don't know how to get the "Result" table to make it in sqlfiddle... for that reason I thought that it was easier in this way

Comment: @user2528601 easier for you maybe... harder on **everyone** else who could potentially help you :P

Comment: ID1 has 4 records But your screenshot shows only the two records with the highest L_value and next highest.  Are you wanting to limit to only the highest and next highest? or are you wanting to pivot all the data?

Comment: @user2528601 The result table is fine as an image, text, etc. It's the source tables that are nice to have as a starting point in SQLFiddle.

Comment: @Kritner Sorry, if it helps I will do it also in sqlfiddle

Comment: @BryanEargle That's my fault, I want all the records for each serie_id (in that case, ID_1, I would like to show all the records in the table2 with ID_1)

Comment: @user2528601 table1 and table2 schemas are the important ones... because as you said you're unsure how to arrive at `Result`.  A description of what makes up `Result` would be helpful however.  It looks like you're looking for a pivot utilizing all records on `table2` joined with `table1` as your result, that sound about right?  How is the order of the columns in `Result` determined?

Comment: @user2528601 you will not be able to do this via Pivoting

Comment: @user2528601 Do you have an unknown number of values in `table2`? Or do you have a limited number of `L_value`, etc?

Comment: Here is the sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/db052
The order is not really important (it would be good to order by L_value, but is not critical).
@bluefeet The number of values in table2 is unknown...sometimes is 1 record for an ID, another times 4 or 5...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get your final result, you are going to have to implement a variety of methods including unpivot, pivot, along with the use of a windowing function like `row_number()`.

Since you have multiple columns in `Table2` that need to be pivoted, then you will need to unpivot them first.  This is the reverse of pivot, which converts your multiple columns into multiple rows. But before you unpivot, you need some value to identify the values of each row using `row_number()` - sounds complicated, right?

First, query `table2` using the windowing function `row_number()`. This creates a unique identifier for each row and allows you to easily be able to associate the values for `id_1` from any of the others.

```
select serie_id, l_value, lrms, latTmax, Rdc,
    rn = cast(row_number() over(partition by serie_id order by serie_id)
              as varchar(10))
from table2;
```

See [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f8324/7).  Once you've created this unique identifier, then you will `unpivot` the `L_value`, `lrms`, `latTmax`, and `rdc`. You can unpivot the data using several different methods, including the unpivot function, CROSS APPLY, or UNION ALL.

```
select serie_id,
  col, value
from
(
  select serie_id, l_value, lrms, latTmax, Rdc,
    rn = cast(row_number() over(partition by serie_id order by serie_id)
              as varchar(10))
  from table2 
) d
cross apply 
(
  select 'L_value_'+rn, L_value union all
  select 'lrms_'+rn, lrms union all
  select 'latTmax_'+rn, latTmax union all
  select 'Rdc_'+rn, Rdc
) c (col, value)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f8324/8). The data from `table2` is not in a completely different format that can be pivoted into the new columns:

```
| SERIE_ID |       COL | VALUE |
|----------|-----------|-------|
|     id_1 | L_value_1 |    67 |
|     id_1 |    lrms_1 |   400 |
|     id_1 | latTmax_1 |   400 |
|     id_1 |     Rdc_1 |  0.25 |
|     id_1 | L_value_2 |    90 |
|     id_1 |    lrms_2 |   330 |
|     id_1 | latTmax_2 |   330 |
|     id_1 |     Rdc_2 |  0.35 |
```

The final step would be to PIVOT the data above into the final result:

```
select serie_id, maturity, strategy, lifetime, l_max, w_max, h_max,
  L_value_1, lrms_1, latTmax_1, Rdc_1,
  L_value_2, lrms_2, latTmax_2, Rdc_2,
  L_value_3, lrms_3, latTmax_3, Rdc_3,
  L_value_4, lrms_4, latTmax_4, Rdc_4
from
(
  select t1.serie_id, t1.maturity, t1.strategy, t1.lifetime,
    t1.l_max, t1.w_max, t1.h_max,
    t2.col, t2.value
  from table1 t1
  inner join
  (
    select serie_id,
      col, value
    from
    (
      select serie_id, l_value, lrms, latTmax, Rdc,
        rn = cast(row_number() over(partition by serie_id order by serie_id)
                  as varchar(10))
      from table2 
    ) d
    cross apply 
    (
      select 'L_value_'+rn, L_value union all
      select 'lrms_'+rn, lrms union all
      select 'latTmax_'+rn, latTmax union all
      select 'Rdc_'+rn, Rdc
    ) c (col, value)
  ) t2
    on t1.serie_id = t2.serie_id
) d
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for col in (L_value_1, lrms_1, latTmax_1, Rdc_1,
              L_value_2, lrms_2, latTmax_2, Rdc_2,
              L_value_3, lrms_3, latTmax_3, Rdc_3,
              L_value_4, lrms_4, latTmax_4, Rdc_4)
) p;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f8324/6).

If you have an unknown number of values in `Table2` then you will need to use dynamic SQL to create a sql string that will be executed.  Converting the above code to dynamic sql is pretty easy once you have the logic correct. The code will be:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols 
    = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(col+cast(rn as varchar(10))) 
             from 
             (
               select rn = cast(row_number() over(partition by serie_id order by serie_id)
                  as varchar(10))
               from table2
             ) d
             cross apply
             (
               select 'L_value_', 0 union all
                select 'lrms_', 1 union all
                select 'latTmax_', 2 union all
                select 'Rdc_', 3
             ) c (col, so)
             group by col, rn, so
             order by rn, so
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query = N'SELECT serie_id, maturity, strategy, lifetime, l_max, 
                w_max, h_max,' + @cols + N' 
              from 
             (
               select t1.serie_id, t1.maturity, t1.strategy, t1.lifetime,
                t1.l_max, t1.w_max, t1.h_max,
                t2.col, t2.value
              from table1 t1
              inner join
              (
                select serie_id,
                  col, value
                from
                (
                  select serie_id, l_value, lrms, latTmax, Rdc,
                    rn = cast(row_number() over(partition by serie_id order by serie_id)
                              as varchar(10))
                  from table2 
                ) d
                cross apply 
                (
                  select ''L_value_''+rn, L_value union all
                  select ''lrms_''+rn, lrms union all
                  select ''latTmax_''+rn, latTmax union all
                  select ''Rdc_''+rn, Rdc
                ) c (col, value)
              ) t2
                on t1.serie_id = t2.serie_id
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(value)
                for col in (' + @cols + N')
            ) p '

exec sp_executesql @query
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f8324/12)

Both versions will give a result of:

```
| SERIE_ID | MATURITY | STRATEGY | LIFETIME | L_MAX | W_MAX | H_MAX | L_VALUE_1 | LRMS_1 | LATTMAX_1 | RDC_1 | L_VALUE_2 | LRMS_2 | LATTMAX_2 |  RDC_2 | L_VALUE_3 | LRMS_3 | LATTMAX_3 |  RDC_3 | L_VALUE_4 | LRMS_4 | LATTMAX_4 |  RDC_4 |
|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------|-------|-------|-----------|--------|-----------|-------|-----------|--------|-----------|--------|-----------|--------|-----------|--------|-----------|--------|-----------|--------|
|     id_1 |        3 |        1 |        2 |   2.2 |   1.4 |   1.4 |        67 |    400 |       400 |  0.25 |        90 |    330 |       330 |   0.35 |       120 |    370 |       370 |    0.3 |       180 |    330 |       300 |   0.35 |
|     id_2 |        3 |        1 |        2 |   3.4 |   1.8 |   2.1 |       260 |    300 |       300 |   0.4 |       360 |    280 |       280 |   0.45 |    (null) | (null) |    (null) | (null) |    (null) | (null) |    (null) | (null) |
|     id_3 |        3 |        1 |   (null) |  24.5 |  14.5 |    15 |        90 |    370 |       370 |   0.3 |    (null) | (null) |    (null) | (null) |    (null) | (null) |    (null) | (null) |    (null) | (null) |    (null) | (null) |
|     id_4 |        3 |        1 |   (null) |    28 |  24.5 |    14 |       160 |    340 |       340 |   0.4 |    (null) | (null) |    (null) | (null) |    (null) | (null) |    (null) | (null) |    (null) | (null) |    (null) | (null) |
```